# How to customize Gitlab LDAP authentication function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ldap, gitlab

I want to write some logs in the `login` function of *LDAP authentication* functions of my installed Gitlab.

I added the required lines in the following file (Line 3):
[image]

And after that I did some login tries in the login form of the Gitlab.

But as you see above, the `debug` file doesn't created.

What am I need to do? Does it require any recompile or something?

Note that I also restarted the service using the following command, but nothing changed:

`# gitlab-ctl restart`

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image. Not only is text easier to read, it is easier to index and search, helping future readers find your question.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you put the logging code in the wrong place. Try putting the logging in `#login` instead of `::login` or look for a better hook depending on what it is you are trying to log.

See the official documentation for more information about LDAP [setup](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/how_to_configure_ldap_gitlab_ce/index.html) and [troubleshooting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap.html).